# Research on gender and academic misconduct

Tags: reference-request, research-misconduct, gender, reproducible-research

In professor [David Shanks](https://sites.google.com/site/davidshanksucl/)' talk "*[Does social science tell the truth? (2016)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jt7gEAoUl8s)*" at 15:14 he claims that there is an apparent gender bias among his examples of people that have committed [academic fraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_dishonesty) in the form making up or fudging data. This list includes Lawrence Sanna, Dirk Smeesters, Diedrich Stapel, Jens Forster, Michael LaCour, Marc Hauser, and Adam Savine.

David Shanks follows this observation about his collated list of examples with a claim that this gender bias has been confirmed in the literature, but doesn't provide a reference. What literature is he alluding to? Is there serious research on the matter?

Comment: As this is now a clear reference request, all the comments discussing the methodology of this hypothetical study have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127479/discussion-on-question-by-galen-research-on-gender-and-academic-misconduct). Please read [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230/7734) before posting another comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an interest in scientific fraud, I recommend the retractionwatch.com blog. E.g., they [covered](https://retractionwatch.com/2013/01/22/are-men-more-likely-to-commit-scientific-misconduct/) the study "Males Are Overrepresented among Life Science Researchers Committing Scientific Misconduct" by [Fang, Bennett & Casadevall (2013)](https://doi.org/10.1128/mBio.00640-12):

> Of the 72 faculty members found to have committed misconduct, only 9 were female, or one-third of the number that would have been predicted from their overall representation among life sciences faculty.

So, yes, there is serious research on scientific fraud. You should be able to find more recent studies if you spend more time on a literature search than the 60 seconds I've invested.